# Why human die, what is the meaning of life?

Tags: life, meaning-of-life

I want to know, why human die? What is the meaning of life? I could die tomorrow. What's the meaning of all these things?

Comment: No meaning at all...

Comment: You can consider [Existentialism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existentialism/) and [Albert Camus](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/camus/).

Comment: Consider Nonduality. It is a far, far better thing than Existentialism. Research in to nonduality is under the heading of non-symbolic consciousness.

Answer (score 4):

Not only humans die. Other animals die too.

From the perspective of evolution dying of old animals gives way to a new generation, better adapted to a changing environment.

I do not recognize a higher meaning of life. Nature exists billions of years without animals. Nevertheless from the perspective of the single human individuum: We are able to choose a meaning for our own life. And if we are fortunate, then we succeed in doing so.

Comment: I upvoted, but would like to note that happiness is not necessarily the mark of a meaningful life.

Comment: @nir I changed *happy* to *fortunate*. That was a linguistic misunderstanding. Of course I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

For most human beings, meaning itself is enough reason for existing.   One could fundamentally replace meaning with pleasure as a basic unit of meaning, which better fits with other life forms too.

Comment: I am quite sure you can see that this is circular. But, hey, that doesn't mean it cannot be the case. Stranger things have happened.